# Can an Albino Shark stay with a guppy in the same tank?

Tags: fish, community-aquarium

I recently bought a few guppies and two albino sharks. I have a seven gallon tank. Can I keep both of them together or separate the guppies in my five gallon tank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly a single albino shark shouldn't be in a tank this small at all let alone 2 of them. They grow to around 5 - 6in, have a high metabolism, and they have a moderately large body mass when adults. I'd recommend about a 40 - 50 gallon minimum for them, ideally 75+ for multiple so they have adequate room to swim.